# Burst-mode with iPhone and AVFoundation

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

I want to implement burst-mode (5 shots in rapid succession) using the AVFoundation framework, but am having difficulty.

```
for(int imgNum = 0; imgNum < nImages; imgNum++)
{
    float dT = imgNum*4.0 - (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime);
    NSLog(@"Waiting for %.02f seconds...\n",dT);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:dT];
    [self takeStill:videoConnection];
}

- takeStill:(AVCaptureConnection*)videoConnection
{
    [stillOut captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     if(error)
         NSLog(@"%s",[[error localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     // {...} Save as a png
 }];
}
```

Taking one image this way works fine. Seemingly, sleeping the thread causes the completion handler to never fire until all `nImages` are taken, and the result is that `imageSampleBuffer` is NULL. What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
- (void)shoot:(NSNumber *)counter {
    int n = [counter intValue];
    if (n > 0) {
        [self takeStill:videoConnection];
        [self performSelector:@selector(shoot:) 
                   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:n - 1] 
                   afterDelay:<# your delay #>];
    }
}
```

Start shooting with `[self shoot:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]`.

Also, you can try shooting several times without waiting. IIRC AVFoundation will queue a few still image requests for you.